# Toolbar Title not showing when CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my MainActivity I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. By default the toolbar it is expanded. But I want it to be collapsed. So as suggested in a StackOverflow question I used the `AppBarLayout` class to make it collapsed by default, using this code:

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

This works fine, excepting one thing. The toolbar title doesn't show up anymore, not even if I expand and collapse the toolbar manually. If I do not collapse the toolbar by default then the title is showing, but if I change the `imageView` from the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` then the title dissapear.

Here is my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` code:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout), EXTRA_IMAGE);
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Search Activity");
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleGravity(Gravity.START);
```

My question is: Am I not setting up the title correctly or am I not collapsing the toolbar in the right way? how can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which version of support library are you using? this sounds like a bug that CollapsingToolbarLayout had some time ago...

Comment: @BartekLipinski The last version. my app build.gradle says:  `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'`  `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'`    `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'`    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems to be a bug of `support-v4, appcompat-v7 v24.2.0` as related [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221403).

Probably the next release will fix the issue.

I fixed it by temporally downgrading to `v24.1.1` the following libraries in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

Comment: Still there in: `24.2.1`

Comment: @ejohansson The bug wasn't fixed in version `24.2.1`?

Comment: Correct, I'm seeing the same issue especially on older SDK versions. I'm also seeing weird title scrolling behavior. Title scrolls in along the positive Y axis instead of negative Y, hence it appears to be hidden/gone when you collapse the toolbar.